# In google Map If we not use `sync` and `defer` what will happen

Tags: html, css, api, google-maps

I'm working on google map API. I have added `sync` and `defer` to take less time to load. But after adding `async` it will affect to other sections.

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap" 
async defer></script>
```

If we do not use async and defer what will happen. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use the **async** in the script, the script will be loaded synchronously by the browser. But still, the Map will load without any issues.
As mentioned on Google Docs
`The async attribute lets the browser render the rest of your website while the Maps JavaScript API loads. When the API is ready, it will call the function specified using the callback parameter.`

An explanation for **defer**:
`This Boolean attribute is set to indicate to a browser that the script is meant to be executed after the document has been parsed, but before firing DOMContentLoaded.
Scripts with the defer attribute will prevent the DOMContentLoaded event from firing until the script has loaded and finished evaluating.`